# Name of argumentation in a discussion

Tags: argumentation

Some weeks ago I was discussing with a friend. I criticized Trump about something and then my friend replied "OK, but *what about Obama*?". This question was aimed at removing attention from Trump and discuss about something else, which, albeit relevant, was not the main topic of the discussion. Moreover, my friend was assuming that I prefer Obama to Trump, which is not necessarily true (I might dislike them both). On top of that, he is not really saying that what Trump did was correct; he just said that Obama did it *too*.

What I would like to know is: what is the name of this argument and how do people usually handle it? This kind of argumentation is used a lot by politicians, e.g. when criticized about something, they reply saying that the politicians from other parties did similar things (just like my friend did).

This question might not be suitable for this community, so I will apology in advance if that's the case and I will erase the question, but I didn't know where else to post it.

Comment: The argument is “tu quoque”, “you’re another”. You’re right that it doesn’t prove anything. The argument is just intended to throw a monkey wrench into the discussion.

Comment: This particular form of *tu quoque* is often called ["whataboutism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism). But let me caution you. First, one does not get to decide unilaterally what is or is not the "main topic of the discussion", opponents are free to bring up what *they* think is relevant. And second, there is no "correct" in politics, it isn't a playground for moral absolutes. To plausibly criticize political actions one needs to establish that they step out of a muddy line in a messy field, *compared to typical behavior*. So what your friend did isn't as fallacious as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tu quoque fallacy is so common in political debates that it has a special name: the "whattabout" or "whattaboutism". Plentiful textbook examples of the whattabout can be found in the interactions between the press and the trumpists Huckabee, Spicer, Conway and McEnany.